# How to use smooth lines command correctly?

Tags: plot, line, smoothing

I have a simple data with several points, and I want to connect them with lines. My problem is that I cannot get accurate result with any of the smooth functions. Csplines completely fails when I try to use it, and Bezier function dosen't give accurate results.Can anyone hep me?
Here is the data.

```
0           0 

0.003092146 833.7105751 

0.006184292 1667.414966

0.009276438 2464.19295

0.012368584 3148.379716

0.01546073  3680.191713

0.018552876 4033.685838

0.021645022 4198.16945

0.024737168 4166.085343

0.027829314 3924.137291

0.030921459 3416.376005

0.034013605 2555.856524

0.034206865 1464.124923
```

Comment: could you maybe share your Code and your plots? Also in which language are you working?

Comment: I'm working in gnuplot. Here is my code.

Comment: set samples 1000 (new line), plot "data that is given" smooth bezier , \ "data" - ploting points